# Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L drivers for CentOS

Tags: drivers, graphics, centos

Recently installed CentOS on Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L motherboard everything works well except the graphics are a bit laggy, so I'm wondering if it hasn't got the drivers in place.

Where do I locate the drivers for this motherboard as I can't find them on the manufacturer's site and they aren't located on the DVD that came with the motherboard.

Comment: did you try searching the CentOS repositories for the intel driver?

Comment: amm.. how do i do that?