# How do I get my USB / Network to work on CentOS 6 on Lenovo g470?

Tags: drivers, centos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L drivers for CentOS](https://superuser.com/questions/166986/gigabyte-ga-g31m-es2l-drivers-for-centos)

I have installed CentOS on this laptop.

My problem now neither the USB drivers are working, not even my network card...

Comment: Related/Similar: [Gigabyte GA-G31M-ES2L drivers for CentOS](http://superuser.com/questions/166986/gigabyte-ga-g31m-es2l-drivers-for-centos)

Answer (score 1):

Centos is based on Red Hat. You can check to see if the hardware components are supported right here:

https://hardware.redhat.com/

If it is not, you may have to compile support for the hardware. At that point, it may be easier just to install Ubuntu on it instead.